# Disable method evaluation inside template

Tags: go, templates, go-templates, goland

I am using Go for template evaluation and the following is my use case.

We have our application in which we ask customers to include prefixed-based placeholders along with their text.

E.g.:

```
my name is {$.PRE.FIRSTNAME}
```

This will be automatically replaced with their first name, this is just a simple text, there will be more complex text which will be entered by the customer. it can even be a HTML.

following is the code snippet

Over here the first templateText works perfectly file and the second commented one doesn't work. it throws an exception stating a function not defined.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "html/template"
    "log"
)

// OuterObject  object
type OuterObject struct {
    PRE *InnerObject
}

// InnerObject macro object
type InnerObject struct {
    FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME string
}

func main() {
    // This works perfectly.
    templateText := "my name is {$.PRE.FIRSTNAME}  "
    // templateText := "my name is {$.PRE.FIRSTNAME} ().push(function() { globalAml.display('sss') };"
    //
    // Above templateText fails with exception :
    // function "globalAml" not defined
    //
    o := &OuterObject{
        PRE: &InnerObject{
            FIRSTNAME: "fName",
            LASTNAME:  "lName",
        },
    }

    var doc bytes.Buffer
    t, err := template.New("test").Delims("{", "}").Parse(templateText)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error parsing tag", err)
    }
    err1 := t.Execute(&doc, o)
    if err1 != nil {
        log.Println("Error Execute tag", err1)
    }
    log.Println("Final text ", doc.String())
}
```

Can anyone help me to ignore the method calls and just to replace the prefixed-based placeholders.

Comment: The template interprets `{ globalAml.display('sss') }` as an action.  Either change the [template delimiters](https://pkg.go.dev/html/template#Template.Delims) to something other than {} or quote the {} inside the template.

Comment: @CeriseLimón worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was temporarily able to handle this case by changing the code snippet to following :

```golang
t, err := template.New("test").Delims("{$", "}").Parse(templateText)
```

I know this will fail in cases where customer entering a text containing these above delimiters.

Thanks a lot, guys.

Answer (score 0):

Your second substitution fails because `{` and `}` are the template delimiters. You need to quote them to make this work:

```
templateText := "my name is {$.PRE.FIRSTNAME} ().push(function() {`{`} globalAml.display('sss') {`}`};"
```

Comment: I dont have control over the text entered by the customer, any other solution to handle it from code. ?

Comment: @ShivaKumarSS There are other solutions (e.g. you could define another pair of delimiter characters) but they *also* require changing the `templateText`. Fundamentally, the current `templateText` is ambiguous, so you simply won’t get around changing that. If you know that the actual templates always start with `$`, you could preprocess the user input and replace any `{` that isn’t immediately followed by `$`. However, if you want to allow the user more freedom, this approach quickly becomes extremely complex.